# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader$ECDSAKeyPairParser,

Tags: java

I am using bcprov-jdk15-146.jar for PEMParser.java class and oracle java 7,

But at line

PEMReader pvtPemReader = getPvtPemReader(pvtFileReader);

Sample Code:

```
public static String signData(String pvtKeyFileName, String dataToSign, String signatureAlg)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException
    {
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(pvtKeyFileName);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(signatureAlg, "BC");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        
        signature.update(dataToSign.getBytes());
        byte signatureBytes[] = signature.sign();
        
        return byteArrayToHexString(signatureBytes);
    }

private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String pvtKeyFileName)
        throws IOException
    {
        FileReader pvtFileReader = getPVTKeyFile(new File(pvtKeyFileName));
        PEMReader pvtPemReader = getPvtPemReader(pvtFileReader);
        KeyPair keyPair = (KeyPair)pvtPemReader.readObject();
        pvtFileReader.close();
        pvtFileReader = null;
        pvtPemReader.close();
        pvtPemReader = null;
        return keyPair.getPrivate();
    }
```

I got the following Exception:

```
exception thrown by servlet Genlink: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader$ECDSAKeyPairParser, method=parseObject(Lorg/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemObject;)Ljava/lang/Object;, pc=26; Type Mismatch, argument 0 in signature org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/AlgorithmIdentifier.<init>:(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/DERObjectIdentifier;Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable;)V does not match
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader$ECDSAKeyPairParser.parseObject(Lorg/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemObject;)Ljava/lang/Object; @26: JBinvokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/bouncycastle/asn1/DERObjectIdentifier'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @26
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader$ECDSAKeyPairParser', 'org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemObject', 'org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Sequence', 'org/bouncycastle/asn1/sec/ECPrivateKeyStructure' }
    stack: { 'uninitialized', 'uninitialized', 'org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier' }
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 124] => handler: 125
    bci [0, 124] => handler: 128
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at my.com.cgu.genlink.common.filter.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:33)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at my.com.cgu.genlink.common.filter.SessionTimeOutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeOutFilter.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

Comment: With your experience you should know how to format code properly, Bouncy 1.46 is _way_ old (but so is j7), your 'sample' code is inconsistent with your stacktrace, and that errorcode looks more like IBM than Sun/Oracle to me, but at core `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier` is a subclass of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObjectIdentifier` so it _should_ be assignable and I don't know why the verifier thinks it isn't.